# jquery not returning the element

Tags: jquery

I was developed a jquery plugin

```
$(someelment).myplugin();
```

working perfect.

When the other plugin is include error displaying

```
$(someelment).myplugin().otherplugin();
```

and the below case also working.

```
$(someelment).otherplugin().myplugin();
```

Comment: Show `myplugin`'s code, it's not returning the object as your title implies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you have to return `this` (or `this.each()`) in your plugin functions in order to maintain chainability of plugins. If you miss that, you may not be able to call another plugin - just your problem. [Here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Maintaining_Chainability) is the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a

`return this` or `return this.each()`

statement in your plugin in order for chaining to work properly.